# Android: Trying to access unique Ids with listView

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm having a problem with my listView and getting items retrieved correctly from it. 
My application is an admin app that allows teachers to add lesson notes against specific students. My scenario is as follows:

When the teacher adds a new lesson note to the list it automatically gives it a unique ID

so student 1 (id 1)has lesson notes with ids: 1,3,4,5 and 6

student 2 (id 2)has lesson notes with ids : 2,7,8 and 9

Student 1 has the list view of:1,2,3,4,5

Student 2 has the list view of:1,2,3,4,5

So when student 1 accesses note 1, the query is as follows:  select * from table_lessons where lessonID = 1 and StudentID = 1

Note 2:  select * from table_lessons where lessonID = 2 and StudentID = 1

Note 3:  select * from table_lessons where lessonID = 3 and StudentID = 1

And so on....

But you see that student 1 doesn't have the lesson note '2'  - so the program crashes

I think the position of the listView is throwing the program off...

This is what is in my lessonNotesList class: (UPDATED)

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_lesson_notes_list);
    Button backToMain = (Button)findViewById(R.id.backToMain);
    backToMain.setOnClickListener(this);
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    dyslexiaDb = new DBHelper(this);
    ArrayList array_list = dyslexiaDb.getAllStudents();
    //Creating an ArrayList of contacts data
    //ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,R.layout.list_layout, array_list);
    LessonAdapter adapter = new LessonAdapter(array_list);
    ListView listView = new ListView(this);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
            // the id parameter returns the adapter's getItemId method
            //intent.putExtra("lesson_id", id);
        }
    }); 
}
```

LessonAdapter class:

```
public class LessonAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    private ArrayList<LessonNotesData> lessonNotes;

    public LessonAdapter(ArrayList<LessonNotesData> lessonNotes) {
        this.lessonNotes = lessonNotes;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount(){
        // get the number of lessons stored in the array
        return lessonNotes.size();
    }
    @Override
    public LessonNotesData getItem(int item){
        // return the lesson object
        return lessonNotes.get(item);
    }
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int item){
        // return the lessonNotes id
        return getItem(item).getLessonID();
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        // inflate the layout item you want to use
        view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.activity_lesson_notes_list, viewGroup, false);
        //((TextView)     view.findViewById(R.id.listViewMain)).setText(getItem(i).getDate());
        return view;
    }
}
```

activity_lesson_notes_list.xml

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/backToMain"
    android:layout_width="185dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/backBtn"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/AddNew"
    android:layout_width="188dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"    
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="Add New" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listViewMain"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="685dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/AddNew"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/backToMain"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/backToMain">
</ListView>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are using objects for your lessons so I made a mock class that would hold the lesson object as an example. Below are some code snippets that should set you on the right track. If you have more questions, feel free to ask.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    LessonAdapter adapter = new LessonAdapter(getStudentsLessons());
    ListView listView = new ListView(this);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
            // the id parameter returns the adapter's getItemId method
            intent.putExtra("lesson_id", id);
        }
    });

}

public class LessonAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private ArrayList<Lesson> lessons;

    public LessonAdapter(ArrayList<Lesson> lessons) {
        this.lessons = lessons;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // get the number of lessons
        return lessons.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Lesson getItem(int i) {
        // return the lesson object
        return lessons.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        // return the lesson's id
        return getItem(i).getId();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        // inflate the layout item you want to use
        // below is using the build in simple list item, but you can sub in a custom one if you want
        view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, viewGroup, false);
        ((TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).setText(getItem(i).getName());
        return view;
    }
}

public class Lesson {
    private int id;
    private String name;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is not with the `ListView` but with why `dyslexiaDb.getAllLessonNotes(studentID)` returns `2` when clearly that lesson has not been assigned to student `1`.

Ideally, your SQL inside `getAllLessonNotes()` should be like

```
SELECT * FROM table_lessons WHERE StudentID = 1
```

which would return a `List` of custom `Lesson` objects which can still be used with a normal `ArrayAdapter` if you override `Lesson#toString()` appropriately.

This also helps avoid making the second database call to retrieve all the lesson details with

```
 select * from table_lessons where lessonID = 2 and StudentID = 1
```

because you can directly pass the `Lesson` object to your detail activity via the `Intent`.